# How does Python know that it has to read a file line by line when the sequence part of the for loop is a file?

Tags: python

Here I open the second value of the `sys.argv` list for reading, store the file object in variable `f` and then process the file line by line:

```
f = open(sys.argv[1])
for line in f:
```

How does Python know that it has to read file line by line? At first I thought that `line` itself has some sort of special meaning, but I could also do `for xine in f:` and it still works. Does Python know that it has to read a file line by line if the sequence part of the for loop is a file(or file object)?

Comment: The `file` type has an `__iter__()` method that returns a line-by-line iterator. Any type (including those you write yourself) can have this method to indicate how it should behave when being iterated over. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does Python know that it has to read a file line by line if the
>   sequence part of the for loop is a file(or file object)?

Yes, that's how file objects were implemented in Python.

A file object is an iterator object, whose `next` method returns a line. Putting that in a `for` simply calls the `next` method repeatedly and what you get are lines of the file being assigned in succession to the loop variable: `line`, `xine` or any other valid assignment target.

---

```
for line in f:
    # do something with line
```

is synonymous to doing:

```
line = next(f)
# do something with line
line = next(f)
# do something with line
...
# repeat until EOF
```